# Storing Session data Fails, due to a following redirect

Tags: php, session, cookies, httprequest, http-status-code-302

I want to store session data right before a 302 redirect occurs, to the same page, only without some of the original request parameters.

for example:

1. Visitor goes to `domain.com/?ab_saveme=hey`
2. `hey` value will get stored
3. Visitor will get redirected to `domain.com/`
4. Page will output `hey`

---

This is the code I came with, it does the redirect, but it doesn't manage to store the value (`hey` is not being outputed).

Without the redirect block, it does store it correct.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_name("hello");
$_SESSION['cache']=$_GET['ab_saveme']; // store the `saveme` value

// begin self redirect code

function unparse_url($parsed_url) {
  $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
  $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
  $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
  $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : '';
  $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : '';
  $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
  $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
  $query    = !empty($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . trim($parsed_url['query'], '&') : '';
  $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
  return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";
}

function strip_query($url, $query_to_strip) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  $parsed['query'] = preg_replace('/(^|&)'.$query_to_strip.'[^&]*/', '', $parsed['query']);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";


$new_url = (strip_query($url, 'ab')); # or whatever query you want to strip/keep


$filtered = array_filter(array_keys($_GET), function($k) {
    return strpos($k, 'ab') === 0;
});

if ( !empty($filtered) ) {
    header ("Location: $new_url");
}

// end self redirect code

echo $_SESSION['cache']; // needs to echo original `saveme` value
echo session_id();
if (is_writable(session_save_path()))
{
    echo "writable";
}
?>
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to Zimmi, I noticed I was re-storing a null value.

Is the best practice to handle this is change:

```
$_SESSION['cache']=$_GET['ab_saveme']; // store the `saveme` value
```

into:

```
if (!empty($_GET['ab_saveme'])) {
$_SESSION['cache']=$_GET['ab_saveme']; // store the `saveme` value
}
```

Or is there a better way? as I might have to do this for various parameters (such as `ab_1`,`ab_2`)

Comment: After the redirect, `$_GET['ab_saveme']` is null, as the parameter is not anymore in the query string, so you store `NULL` inside the `$_SESSION['cache']`...

Comment: @Zimmi Thanks! didn't think about it. I edited my question, do you think my edited code is best practice to handle this?

Comment: Sure that is the way to go. First check if `$_GET['ab_saveme']` exists and store it only if it exists. But before storing it, as you want to echo it again, you will need to sanitize it according to your needs, to avoid xss and so on, with function htmlspecialchars, for example.